# LINQのクェリー式構文のSelectでインデックスを使用するには？

Tags: linq

VB + LINQ でプログラムを作っています．対象から抽出するときにそのindexも欲しいのです．例えば以下のドキュメントのサンプルはC#ですが、メソッド構文でそれを実現しています．

[Select<TSource,TResult>(IEnumerable, Func<TSource,Int32,TResult>)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1)

VBでもSelectのメソッド構文でできることは試して理解出来ました．クェリー式構文で同じことをやりたいのですが、これはできないのでしょうか？いろいろWebを当たってみましたがわかりません．すみませんが教えてください．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBであれ、C#であれ、クエリ式構文で使用できるキーワードがそれぞれどのメソッド呼び出しに対応するかは言語仕様で定められています。

- [標準クエリ演算子のクエリ式構文 (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-expression-syntax-for-standard-query-operators)
- [標準クエリ演算子のクエリ式構文 (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-expression-syntax-for-standard-query-operators)

ここにindex付きSelectが記載されていない以上、クエリ式構文で表現することはできません。

どうしても使用する場合は、メソッド構文でSelectを呼び出し、その結果をFrom句に渡すぐらいでしょうか。